# Meaning of 鳥さえ in the song ウィンターワンダーランド

Tags: song-lyrics, particle-さえ

In this [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCvjKIqPo44&t=0s&index=9&list=PL5yC_Ix1usLxclu5MhFWbHWZVgtHRB6tC), the lyrics go「青い鳥**さえ**いつもさえずり。」

I'm not sure what さえ means in this context. Is this the particle さえ or does it mean somthing else?

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the particle-さえ ("*Even* bluebirds are tweeting"). Although it does sound a bit weird to me, too, this is the only possible interpretation. It's also clearly different from [what's said in the original lyrics](http://kidssongs.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-34.html), but this happens all the time in English-to-Japanese translation of lyrics.

Comment: I suspect that the translator used the particle さえ as a deliberate echo of the さえ in さえずり.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi That never occurred to me :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a rhyme to impress you with this bit of confusion.
I often run into those kind of lyrics in J-pop made later than 00's.